# Como colorir a legenda de acordo com o gráfico no R

Tags: r, plot

Olá pessoal eu tenho um gráfico no R e gostaria de fazer a legenda igual ao gráfico.
segue abaixo o comando usado e a imagem do gráfico.

```
control = c(100,100,100,100,100)
dez = c(100,90,0,0,0)
cinco = c(100,100,100,50,0)
dois = c(100,100,100,100,0)
hours = c(0,24,48,60,72)

plot(control~hours,ylim = c(0,120),xlim = c(0,80),type = 'l',col='black',pch = 1,lwd = 2)

points(control~hours,t = 'p',pch = 16,col='green')
points(dez~hours,type = 'l',pch = 16,col='black',lwd = 2)
points(dez~hours,t = 'p',pch = 16,col='blue')
points(cinco~hours,t = 'l',col='black',lwd = 2)
points(cinco~hours,t = 'p',pch = 16,col='red')
points(dois~hours,t = 'l',col='black',lwd =2)
points(dois~hours,t = 'p',pch = 16,col='orange')

legend('bottomleft',legend = c('Control','10 mg/mL','5 mg/mL','2,5 mg/mL'),col = "black",lty = 1,lwd=2 ,pch=16)
```

E com isso gerou esse gráfico.

[image: Gráfico]

O que eu gostaria de fazer é pintar as bolas da legenda de acordo com a cor que está no gráfico.
Obrigado.

Comment: tente construir seu gráfico no ggplot2, será mais fácil associar a legenda ao gráfico, veja minha pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192221/como-reproduzir-um-gr%C3%A1fico-que-foi-criado-com-o-comando-plot-utilizando-o-ggplot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode colocar uma legenda em cima da outra com fundo transparente:

```
legend('bottomleft',
       legend = c('Control','10 mg/mL','5 mg/mL','2,5 mg/mL'),
       col = c("black"), lty = 1, lwd=2, pch = NA)

legend('bottomleft',
       legend = c('Control','10 mg/mL','5 mg/mL','2,5 mg/mL'),
       col = c("green", "blue", "red", "orange"), lty = 0, lwd=2, pch = 16, 
       bg='transparent')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado, era isso que desejava.

Comment: @JoãoPedroPires por nada! Você pode aceitar a resposta clicando no botão de aceitar à esquerda da pergunta.